# Logback DB Appender not logging into Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have a Spring Boot Java web app using Logback and I'm trying to configure it to log into an Oracle DB (Oracle XE).

For some reason Logback is correctly logging on Console and File (as defined in my Logback.xml) but not into the DB.

No exception or error is raised.

This is my POM.xml

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback.db</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-core-db</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback.db</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic-db</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is part of my Logback.xml

```
<appender name="Database-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1</url>
            <user>my_user</user>
            <password>my_password</password>                      
        </connectionSource>     
    </appender>
```

I have also created the required tables, sequence and trigger

```
CREATE SEQUENCE logging_event_id_seq MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE logging_event 
  (
    timestmp         NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    formatted_message  VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL,
    logger_name       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    level_string      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    thread_name       VARCHAR(254),
    reference_flag    SMALLINT,
    arg0              VARCHAR(254),
    arg1              VARCHAR(254),
    arg2              VARCHAR(254),
    arg3              VARCHAR(254),
    caller_filename   VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_class      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_method     VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_line       CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    event_id          NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY
  );

CREATE TRIGGER logging_event_id_seq_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON logging_event
  FOR EACH ROW  
  BEGIN  
    SELECT logging_event_id_seq.NEXTVAL 
    INTO   :NEW.event_id 
    FROM   DUAL;  
  END;
/


CREATE TABLE logging_event_property
  (
    event_id          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    mapped_key        VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    mapped_value      VARCHAR2(1024),
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, mapped_key),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
  
CREATE TABLE logging_event_exception
  (
    event_id         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    i                SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    trace_line       VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, i),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
```

EDIT:

I call the appender in this way:

```
 <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />   
        <appender-ref ref="Database-Appender"/>        
    </root>
```

Running Logback in debug mode I get this error:

```
 ORA-04043 object logging_event does not exists
```

Can be a case sensitive problem due to the fact that my tables are in uppercase?

I re-created the tables in lowercase so:

- logging_event
- logging_event_exception
- logging_event_property

But the same error occurs:

```
problem appending event java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object logging_event does not exists
```

But nothing is written into these tables, and as I said earlier, no configuration errors are thrown by running the web app.

Thanks.

Comment: And you are sure that you use Database-Appender in the logback.xml?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes:  <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console-Appender" />   
        <appender-ref ref="Database-Appender"/>        
    </root>

Comment: and you are sure that the logback.xml is picked up

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, because the other appenders are working fine (Console and FIle appender)

Comment: And the db user is allowed to write to logging_event? You gave the grants?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I edited my answer because I've found this error running logback in debug mode:

problem appending event java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object logging_event does not exists

So I think could be a problem related to the schema but I'm not sure

Comment: This means that your user my_user does not have access to this table. Is it created in a different schema?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes: because the user I use to connect is "system" but the schema is the name of my project es: "my_proj"

Unfortunately I don't know Oracle DB and how it works so I created a default DB "XEPDB1" for the user "system" running the docker image of "Oracle XE".

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: you have to create the tables in the my_user schema

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I created the tables in "my_user" schema since the beginning. I thought the problem was related to the user "system" I put into the DB Appender configuration so I granted ALL privileges to the "my_user" user but the error is the same.

Comment: SOLVED: I had to recreate the tables (in the "my_user" schema") in UPPERCASE and setting "my_user" in the DB Appender connection config.